# How to move a file from FTP location to local directory?

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I am new to mulesoft and I trying to implement following use case.
I want to move files from FTP location to a local directory using Mule. I am using Mule 4.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is attribute in the "On New or Updated File" Component - move to directory. It will delete file from the FTP.

```
<flow name="FTP_Flow">
    <ftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File"  config-ref="FTP_Config" autoDelete="true" moveToDirectory="/tmp" directory="/">
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency />
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </ftp:listener>
</flow>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, this is file transfer from FTP to FTP location. What I am looking for is, is it possible to move the files from FTP location(some server) to my local machine?

Comment: That's from FTP to local. If you like you can copy payload to local by simply using Write component. /tmp is your local folder. On Windows it is c:\tmp - just Java notation.

Comment: I tried, but its creating a /tmp folder inside the ftp folder and moving the files, but I want to move the files on to my desktop folder. Anyways it looks like using Write Component is the only option. Thanks a lot. Let me know if we can do it without write operation. :-)